# Toggle kendo-drawer from top-navigation element

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I have a main-view html, where I created a seperate top-navigation which has a clickable button in it:

```
<top-navigation (drawerClicked)="drawer.toggle()"></top-navigation>
<side-drawer #drawer class="custom-container"></side-drawer>
```

Which sends a toggle to my side-drawer.component.ts:

```
public toggle(): void {
  this.isExpanded = !this.isExpanded;
}
```

Which I want in turn I want to toggle my kendo-drawer:

```
<kendo-drawer-container>
  <kendo-drawer #drawer
      [items]="drawerItems"
      mode="push"
      [mini]="true"
      [width]="200"
      [animation]="true"
      [autoCollapse]="false"
      [expanded]="isExpanded">
  </kendo-drawer>
</kendo-drawer-container>
```

This expands it well, but does not give the toggle animation.

I am not sure what the best way of working for this is. To get the child element in my .ts and set it to toggle that way? Or perhaps import the side-drawer into my top-navigation and set it to toggle directly when the button is clicked in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out in the end.

import viewchild and drawercomponent from kendo in the side-drawer:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { DrawerComponent } from '@progress/kendo-angular-layout';
```

in your export add the drawerComponent tag:

```
export class SideDrawerComponent {
  @ViewChild('drawer')
  drawer!: DrawerComponent;
}
```

then you can simply add the toggle to the toggle() function:

```
public toggle(): void {
  this.isExpanded = !this.isExpanded;
  this.drawer.toggle();
}
```